# visit new file; enter shell script text; without saving/reloading, fontify the buffer to sh-mode

Tags: font-lock

The title of this question basically says all.

Visit a new buffer, let's say 'foo'.
Enter shell script text in the new buffer, let's say "`#!/bin/sh`".

How can I now set the mode to `sh-mode` and fontify the buffer accordingly, without the save buffer as foo, reload buffer sequence?

Answer (score 1):

You can call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `sh-mode` directly or, having added that shebang line, you could use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `normal-mode` which will at that point recognise the shell script content and set `sh-mode`.

Being familiar with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `normal-mode` means you generally don't need to care what the desired mode name is.  I use this frequently enough that I have `(defalias 'nm 'normal-mode)` so that I only need <kbd>M-x</kbd> `nm`.

Obviously if the file is named `foo.sh` then Emacs will pick `sh-mode` by default; but if you have global mode `auto-insert-mode` enabled, then creating a new file `foo` in any `bin/` directory will make Emacs prompt you to treat the file as a shell script as well.

Comment: ARghh! I could have sworn I tried that. It just works. Thank you!  All I now need to do is make a little function that doesn't remove the linum (which I have on globally by default) when I call sh-mode like you suggested.  Again -- thanks!